# Как остледить время метода?

Tags: java

Есть метод который чтото выполняет и я хочу чтоб в консоли выводилось время потраченное на этот метод.Как это реализовать???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
// ...
// ваш код
// ...
long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
System.out.println(elapsed + " ms");
```

Это не очень хороший способ для точных бенчмарков, но для грубого замера подойдет.

Comment: Ничего пока этого хватит для отслежения первой  оптимизации